# How to write a mysql query with case-when-then?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Any thoughts on how to run the following query. I guess I need to use case-when-then along with group by clause. Thanks

Find all customers who have 'BASIC' edition containing atleast (API, CUSTOM_WORKFLOW and FILE_UPLOAD) features or 'TRIAL' edition containing atleast (API, CUSTOM_WORKFLOW) features

```
Customer table

id     name   edition       
---------------------
 1     CO1    BASIC
 2     CO2    TRIAL
 3     CO3    BASIC

Customer_Feature table

id  company_id   feature
------------------------
 1       1        API
 2       1        CUSTOM_WORKFLOW
 3       1        FILE_UPLOAD
 4       2        API
 5       2        CUSTOM_WORKFLOW
 6       2        FILE_SYNC
 7       3        API
 8       3        CUSTOM_WORKFLOW
 9       3        FILE_SYNC
```

This should return only customer with id 1 and 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a need for a `case` statement.  This query uses aggregation so all the features can be compared for a given customer:

```
select c.id
from customers c join
     customer_feature cf
     on c.id = cf.company_id
group by c.id
having sum(c.edition = 'BASIC' and cf.feature in ('API', 'CUSTOM_WORKFLOW', 'FILE_UPLOAD')) = 3 or
       sum(c.edition = 'TRIAL' and cf.feature in ('API', 'CUSTOM_WORKFLOW')) = 2;
```

The `having` clause then looks at the number of relevant features that match for each edition.  This assumes that there are no duplicates in the feature table - if there are duplicates, the query would use `count(distinct)` rather than `sum()`.

EDIT:

To get the result with `count(distinct)` do:

```
having count(distinct case when c.edition = 'BASIC' and cf.feature in ('API', 'CUSTOM_WORKFLOW', 'FILE_UPLOAD') then df.feature end) = 3 or
       count(distinct case when c.edition = 'TRIAL' and cf.feature in ('API', 'CUSTOM_WORKFLOW') then cf.feature end) = 2;
```

Comment: It's not immediately obvious how to get the same result with `count(distinct)`, can you provide an example?

Comment: @AirThomas . . . I added that into the answer, but I don't think it is necessary.  I doubt the features repeat themselves.

Comment: Thanks. It seemed prudent to elaborate, since `sum()` and `count()` treat false comparisons differently, that in the latter case you *do* need the `case` statement after all.